# Regex to create nested dictionary from multiline output of mroute database

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, nested

```
text = """sh forwarding distribution multicast route vrf A group 228.0.0.0 source 209.0.10.145  
(40.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  
Received Packets: 8460 Bytes: 6871184  
Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 3  
Outgoing Interface List Index: 243  
Ethernet2/22/2  
Ethernet6/7/1.11  
Vlan 100  
(41.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  
Received Packets: 8460 Bytes: 6871184  
Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 3  
Outgoing Interface List Index: 243  
Ethernet2/22/2  
Ethernet6/7/1.10  
Ethernet6/7/1.11  
(43.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  
Received Packets: 8460 Bytes: 6871184  
Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 3  
Outgoing Interface List Index: 243  
Ethernet2/22/2  
Ethernet6/7/1.10  
Ethernet6/7/1.11"""


#expected output : Result={s1g1:{“rpf”:Eth12/24/2, ”oiflistIndex”:243,” “oiflists”:[Eth2/22/2,Eth6/7/1.10,Eth6/7/1.11]},s2g2:{……..}…}


#code i tried..

import re
tup_list = []
intf_list = []
dict_1 = {}
result = {'s1g1':{},'s2g2':{},'s3g3':{}}

p1 = re.findall(r'\([\d+\/.*].*|Received Packets:.\d+|Number of Outgoing Interfaces:.\d+|Outgoing Interface List Index:.\d+|[\n]Ethernet.+[\d.*]+|Vlan.[\d+]+', text, re.MULTILINE)
print("matched patterns",p1)

for i in range(0,len(p1)):
    p1[i] = re.sub("\n", "",p1[i])
    
    if 'RPF' in p1[i]:
        tmp = p1[i].split(',')[2]
        tup = ('rpf', tmp.split(':')[1])
        tup_list.append(tup)
    elif ':' in p1[i]:
        tup = (p1[i].split(':')[0], p1[i].split(':')[1])
        tup_list.append(tup)
    elif ('Ethernet' in p1[i]) or ('Vlan' in p1[i]):
        intf_list.append(p1[i])
        print("intf list ",intf_list)
        tup = ('OutIntflist', intf_list)
        tup_list.append(tup)
print("ivide ",tup_list)

for k,v in tup_list: 
    dict_1.setdefault(k, v)
print("dict_1 ",dict_1) 
for k in result:
    result[k] = dict_1
print("\n\nResult : ",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = r"\([\d+\/.*].*|Received Packets:.\d+|Number of Outgoing Interfaces:.\d+|Outgoing Interface List Index:.\d+|\bEthernet.+[\d.*]+|Vlan.[\d+]+"

test_str = ("sh forwarding distribution multicast route vrf A group 228.0.0.0 source 209.0.10.145  \n"
    "(40.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  \n"
    "Received Packets: 8460 Bytes: 6871184  \n"
    "Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 3  \n"
    "Outgoing Interface List Index: 243  \n"
    "Vlan 100  \n"
    "Vlan 100  \n"
    "Ethernet2/22/2  \n"
    "Ethernet6/7/1.11  \n"
    "Vlan 100  \n"
    "(41.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  \n"
    "Received Packets: 8462 Bytes: 6871184\n"
    "Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 2\n"
    "Outgoing Interface List Index: 264  \n"
    "Ethernet2/22/2  \n"
    "Ethernet6/7/1.11\n"
    "(43.45.1.2/32, 235.200.3.80/32), RPF Interface: Ethernet2/24/2, flags: L  \n"
    "Received Packets: 8463 Bytes: 6871184  \n"
    "Number of Outgoing Interfaces: 2 \n"
    "Outgoing Interface List Index: 243  \n"
    "Ethernet2/22/2  \n"
    "Ethernet6/7/1.10")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
sg_pattern = r"(\d.* )"   #(pattern to get (S,G))
record = []
keys_list = []
values_list = list()
dict_1 = {}
new = []
list_rec = []
for i in range(0, len(matches)):
    record.append(matches[i])
    if('(' in matches[i] ):
        keys_list.append(" ".join(matches[i].split(',')[0:2]))
print("keys list :  ",keys_list)
print("\nrecords : ",record) 

# Find the position and split them as each records
pos = [i for i, item in enumerate(record) if re.search(r"(\d.* )", item)]
pos.append(len(record)-1) # get end of list
#print(pos)
my_iter = iter(pos)
for i in range(0, len(pos)-1):
    start_pos = pos[i]
    i = i+1
    end_pos = pos[i] + 1
    list_rec.append(record[start_pos:end_pos])
    #print(start_pos, end_pos)
#print("\nlist record 1 : ", list_rec)

"""Create dictionary from each record, first create tuple and then create the inner dictionary"""
n = len(list_rec)
for j in range(0,n):
    intf_list = []
    tup_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(list_rec[j])):
        if 'RPF' in list_rec[j][i]:
            tmp = list_rec[j][i].split(',')[2]
            tup = ('rpf', tmp.split(':')[1])
            tup_list.append(tup)
        elif ':' in list_rec[j][i]:
            tup = (list_rec[j][i].split(':')[0], list_rec[j][i].split(':')[1])
            tup_list.append(tup)
        elif ('Ethernet' in list_rec[j][i]) or ('Vlan' in list_rec[j][i]):
            intf_list.append(list_rec[j][i])
            #print("intf list ",intf_list)
            tup = ('OutIntflist', intf_list)
            tup_list.append(tup)
    new.append(tup_list)        
#print("tup list ",tup_list)   
#print("\nnew", new)
for i in range(0, len(new)):
    #print("new[{i}]".format(i=i),new[i])
    for k,v in new[i]:
        dict_1.setdefault(k, v)
    #print(dict_1)
    values_list.append([dict_1])
    dict_1 = {}

#print(values_list)   
zip_iterator = zip(keys_list, values_list)
result = dict(zip_iterator) 
print("\nOutput is : \n", result)
```

Comment: Output is : 
==============
 {'(40.45.1.2/32  235.200.3.80/32)': [{'rpf': ' Ethernet2/24/2', 'Received Packets': ' 8460', 'Number of Outgoing Interfaces': ' 3', 'Outgoing Interface List Index': ' 243', 'OutIntflist': ['Vlan 100', 'Vlan 100', 'Ethernet2/22/2', 'Ethernet6/7/1.11', 'Vlan 100']}], '(41.45.1.2/32  235.200.3.80/32)': [{'rpf': ' Ethernet2/24/2', 'Received Packets': ' 8462', 'Number of Outgoing Interfaces': ' 2', 'Outgoing Interface List Index': ' 264', 'OutIntflist': ['Ethernet2/22/2', 'Ethernet6/7/1.11']}], ...}